# How to collect list of filterred objects from sub-collections

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Let's have data structure, which is described below.

```
Class LandResearch {
    Research research;
}

Class Research {
    List<Bonus> bonuses;
}

Class Bonus {
    BonusType bonusType;
    double bonusValue;
}
```

I'am in situation, when I have a `List<LandResearch>` and I have specific `BonusType`. 
I want collect all bonuses, which has given `BonusType`.

It is not problem do it with for cycles, but I would like to manage it with streams.

Existing solution, which I would like to replace.

```
List<Bonus> bonuses = new ArrayList<>();
for (LandResearch landResearch: landResearches) {
    for (Bonus bonus: landResearch.getResearch().getBonuses()){
        if (bonus.getBonusType().equals(searchedBonusType)){
            bonuses.add(bonus);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for help and hints.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `flatMap` to produce a `Stream` of all the `Bonus` instances, then filter and collect to a `List`:

```
List<Bonus> bonuses =
    landResearches.stream() // Stream<LandResearch>
                  .flatMap(l->l.getResearch().getBonuses().stream()) // Stream<Bonus>
                  .filter(b->b.getBonusType().equals(searchedBonusType)) // Stream<Bonus>
                  .collect(Collectors.toList()); // List<Bonus>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case that [kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) is an option for you

```
private fun Collection<LandResearch>.bonuses(wanted: BonusType): List<Bonus> =
        flatMap { it.research.bonuses }.filter { it.bonusType == wanted }
```

Use it like this:

```
val bonusesOfWantedType = listOfLandSearches.bonuses(wantedBonusType)
```